# Create alert based on custom logs by using azure command line tool

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have tried creating metrics alert based on custom log query by using az command line tool. What I have managed to so far is to;

- saving custom log query
- creating action group for sending alert information

What I have not managed to do is to create alert by using *az monitor metrics alert create* command so that it is based on number of results the saved loq query returns. Is it possible to create metric alert based on custom log query by using az command line tool?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the command, the help messages are generally quite useful and detailed:

```
az monitor scheduled-query create --help
```

Here's one example based on a query that worked for me. It assumes you've already created a resource group, workspace and action group:

```bash
RESOURCE_GROUP="ResourceGroupName"
WORKSPACE_NAME="LogAnalyticsWorkspaceName"
ACTION_GROUP_NAME="ActionGroupName"

QUERY='AzureDiagnostics
| where Message contains "Connection successful"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
| order by TimeGenerated desc'

WORKSPACE_ID=$(az monitor log-analytics workspace show \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --workspace-name $WORKSPACE_NAME \
    --query id --out tsv)

az monitor scheduled-query create \
    --name "TestScheduledQuery" \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --scopes $WORKSPACE_ID \
    --description "Test rule" \
    --action $ACTION_GROUP_NAME \
    --evaluation-frequency 5m \
    --mute-actions-duration PT30M \
    --severity 3 \
    --condition "count 'QRY1' > 0" \
    --condition-query QRY1="$QUERY"
```

This example will:

- run every 5 minutes (`--evaluation-frequency`)
- look for new diagnostics fitting the constraints that were generated in the last 5 minutes (`QUERY`)
- if the match count is greater than zero (`--condition`):

  - it'll activate an alert (send a mail, etc. depending on the Action Group in `--action`)
  - and once an alert has fired it will be muted for 30 minutes so that repeated alerts won't spam anyone (`--mute-actions-duration`)

Most of these settings are the defaults anyway, I've just defined them for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Custom log search alerts are of type **microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules**. So you may use the [az monitor scheduled-query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/scheduled-query/monitor/scheduled-query?view=azure-cli-latest) set of commands to manage your Scheduled Query rules (resources).

To create a scheduled query, use the `az monitor scheduled-query create` command:

```
az monitor scheduled-query create --condition
                                  --name
                                  --resource-group
                                  --scopes
                                  [--action]
                                  [--description]
                                  [--disabled {false, true}]
                                  [--evaluation-frequency]
                                  [--location]
                                  [--mad]
                                  [--severity]
                                  [--tags]
                                  [--target-resource-type]
                                  [--window-size]
```

Check the [Azure CLI command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/scheduled-query/monitor/scheduled-query?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_scheduled_query_az_monitor_scheduled_query_create) to know the available parameters and their definitions.

Some other ways of creating Log alerts are described in this document: [Create, view, and manage log alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log)